# java.lang.SecurityException: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required. is it possible to enable permission programatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need incoming call hangup programtically, initially it was working in Android N, but now it is not working.